# Adsene type ad, links with image?

Tags: hyperlink, adsense

can anyone tell me what type of adsense ad is this ?
and how we can have images next to the ad?
It is likely to be available only to premium adsense accounts ?Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0QHv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Matched content ad unit with Ads**, ***where Google will display content from your website pages with few ads of other Advertisers.***

You cannot create such kind of ad units until Google will not invite you and Google invites after certain time based on the quality of website and number of organic searches, page views, visitors.

**So please wait for Google’s invitation in AdSense meanwhile focus on your website to increase organic searches by putting quality content there.**